# python: tkinter/urllib/requests - GUI not responding when running download command

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, urllib

I tried making a GUI where there is a download button and it downloads a file from the internet.
There is also a progressbar which shows progress of the download..

the whole code:

```py
#minimal reproductive example..

import os
import time
import yaml
import urllib
import requests
import tempfile
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

TEMP = tempfile.gettempdir()

def download(progressbar=None): 
    start = time.time()
    url = 'https://proget.whirlpool.repl.co/information.yml'
    local_filename = TEMP+"\\"+url.split('/')[-1]
    url_file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    size= url_file.headers["Content-Length"]    
    print("Starting to download file", end = "\r")
    if progressbar:
        progressbar['maximum'] = int(int(size)/1024)
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            sz = 0
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                f.write(chunk)
                sz = sz+8192
                if progressbar:
                    progressbar['value'] = progressbar['value'] + 8192
    os.system(local_filename)

def Download(*args):
    download(progressbar=pb95)

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)

pb95 = ttk.Progressbar(root,orient='horizontal', mode='determinate',length=500, maximum=1)
pb95.pack(side='top',fill='y')

downloadbtn = tk.Button(root,text='Download',font='Consolas 30', bg='green', fg='white',relief='flat', command=Download)
downloadbtn.pack(side='bottom',fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

but when i click on the download button, the whole window stops responding..
and after some time, when the download is finished, it responds.. and the progressbar becomes 100% done..

Comment: I think that is the expected behavior. The function you call is blocking. My advice would be to use a different `thread` for the download

Comment: @GáborErdős how may i do that?

Comment: You could add `root.update()` to the end of your for loop but threading would be a better idea as already suggested

Comment: @scotty3785 any code suggestions?

Comment: @scotty3785 `root.update()` may still not resolve the issue depending on how long each iteration takes to reach the `.update()`, it will update the window but it may still be pretty unresponsive otherwise, thread is the better option but depending on how much resources the loop needs it may be better to put the not tkinter parts in a separate process and use `Queue`s and `after()` loops to update tkinter (because if a lot of resources are used tkinter may be a bit laggy since it runs on the same process as the thread, if one were to use threads (it also is faster to start a new process))

Comment: @Matiiss Agreed. root.update is a hack that may help without the complexity of threading (not a beginner topic) but certainly isn't the best solution

Comment: @Matiiss `root.update` can handle event bindings so you might see that file one file downloads another one starts. This is a bad idea. Also starting a new process can be very difficult and usually is unnecessary. I suggest using a thread as the best option in this case.

Comment: @TheLizzard I didn't get your point about `root.update()` (if you said that it is not a good idea then I agree), but starting a process is not that much different than starting a thread (thread however is much more simple for beginners since it is possible to simply use some global variables and stuff and calling the function is not that much different (`threading.Thread(target=func).start()` is all it really takes)) but for a process it may be harder to manage communication although from my experience that is not that difficult either (just a bit more code to do that)

Comment: @Matiiss Using a new process takes much more code than using a new thread. And I have never had to use it as `threading` is good enough. In this case a simple `tkinter` loop that uses a global variable to communicate with another thread for the downloading is good enough.

Comment: @Whirlpool-Programmer How long does the `os.system(...)` run for? The file you are downloading is very small so you don't even need to use a `steam` and all of that stuff. It's less than 0.5 kB in size.

Comment: Actually that file is a testing file.. Nothing more.. The main files that the program is intended to download are greater than 20mb..

Comment: @Whirlpool-Programmer Downloading `20 MB` will take about 4 seconds, so you might not even need the `progressbar`. But running it in another thread is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import urllib
import requests
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

# Import threading
from threading import Thread


def download(progressbar=None):
    global progress_value, progress_maximum, progress_done
    progress_value = 0

    url = 'https://proget.whirlpool.repl.co/information.yml'

    # I hard coded a large file for testing
    url = "https://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/21.04/ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
    # I also hard coded in a temp folder for testing
    local_filename = "tmp/"+url.split('/')[-1]
    url_file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    size= url_file.headers["Content-Length"]
    print("Starting to download file")

    # If you want running the file to take 50% of the progressbar uncomment the `*2`
    progress_maximum = int(size) # *2

    file = open(local_filename, "wb")
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
            file.write(chunk)
            progress_value += len(chunk)
    file.close()

    print("Running the file")
    # os.system(local_filename)
    print("Done")
    progress_value = progress_maximum
    progress_done = True

def Download(*args):
    # Add a default value for the value of the progress bar:
    global progress_value, progress_maximum, progress_done
    progress_value = 0
    progress_maximum = 1
    progress_done = False
    # Start the new thread
    new_thread = Thread(target=download, daemon=True)
    new_thread.start()
    # Start the tkinter loop:
    root.after(100, tkinter_download_loop)

def tkinter_download_loop():
    pb95["maximum"] = progress_maximum
    pb95["value"] = progress_value
    # After 100 ms call `tkinter_download_loop` again
    if not progress_done:
        root.after(100, tkinter_download_loop)

root = tk.Tk()

pb95 = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=500)
pb95.pack(side="top", fill="y")

downloadbtn = tk.Button(root, text="Download", command=Download)
downloadbtn.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

First of all, your code had a few mistakes:

- You keep opening the file in `"wb"` mode, which overrides the last chunk that you downloaded.
- You divide the size by 1024 for no reason.
- Also the file you are downloading is very small. There is no need to iterate over it's contents. The code above assumes that you have a large file

Things I did:

- I added a `tkinter` loop that uses global variables to communicate with a new thread.
- That thread downloads the file.
- I also changed the url to a large file (> 1GB) just to check that it's working properly.
- I also changed it so it opens the file only once so we can save the full file

Comment: Ummm `local_filename.open(local_filename, "wb")` ??

Comment: @CoolCloud My bad. I will fix it. Next time feel free to edit any my answers :D